# Generate in between serial numbers Excel 2013

Tags: excel

I have an excel table that contains as for example the below columns:

```
ID#        Name          From       To
ASB0001    Adams           1        3
ASB0002    Robert          4        5
```

Is there any code to generate in between serial number from to as following:

```
ASB0001    Adams      1
ASB0001    Adams      2
ASB0001    Adams      3
ASB0002    Robert     4
ASB0002    Robert     5
```

please note the table contains about 46000 records. your support is highly appreciated,Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use VBA:

```
Range("G:I").Clear
k = 0
For i = 2 To 99999
    If Range("A" & i).Value = "" Then Exit For
    For e = Range("C" & i).Value To Range("D" & i).Value
        k = k + 1
        Range("G" & k).Value = Range("A" & i).Value
        Range("H" & k).Value = Range("B" & i).Value
        Range("I" & k).Value = e
    Next
Next
```

Considering the data start from **A2** to **Dn** (less than 99999).
The data are expanded from the cell **G1** to the cell **Ix**
If you don't want VBA, add the formulas:

```
G2 -> =IF(P2<>"";INDEX($A$2:$A$15;MATCH(ROW(M1);$C$2:$C$4;1));"")
H2 -> =IF(P2<>"";INDEX($B$2:$B$15;MATCH(ROW(M1);$C$2:$C$4;1));"")
I2 -> =IF(ROW(P1)>MAX(D:D);"";ROW(P1))
```

work if the number are continuous.

Comment: Thank you very much I tried the marco and works, Let me try the VBA and the Formula and will feed you back

Answer (score 0):

Give this small macro a try:

```
Sub ReOrganizer()
    Dim s1 As Worksheet, s2 As Worksheet, _
        N As Long, i As Long, M As Long, _
        F As Long, T As Long, ID As String, _
        Nam As String, j As Long

    Set s1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set s2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
    N = s1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    M = 1

    For i = 2 To N
        ID = s1.Cells(i, 1).Value
        Nam = s1.Cells(i, 2).Value
        F = s1.Cells(i, 3).Value
        T = s1.Cells(i, 4).Value
        For j = F To T
            s2.Cells(M, 1).Value = ID
            s2.Cells(M, 2).Value = Nam
            s2.Cells(M, 3).Value = j
            M = M + 1
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

Assumes that the original data is in *Sheet1* and the output is in *Sheet2.*